# com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: request requires HTTP authentication: Unauthorized

Tags: java, web-services

I am trying to access a remote web service.  Am able to get good response from curl like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -k -H "SOAPAction:getUserActivity" --data @testFile.dat https://esp-int.my.company.com:443/UsageService/13.11
```

But from java get error:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: request requires HTTP authentication: Unauthorized
```

Java sets up the security part of the request like this:

```
    String SECURITY_NAMESPACE = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd";
    QName securityQName = new QName(SECURITY_NAMESPACE, "Security");
    SOAPElement security = soapFactory.createElement(securityQName);
    QName usernameTokenQName = new QName(SECURITY_NAMESPACE, "UsernameToken");
    SOAPElement usernameToken = soapFactory.createElement(usernameTokenQName);
    QName usernameQName = new QName(SECURITY_NAMESPACE, "Username");
    SOAPElement theUsername = soapFactory.createElement(usernameQName);
    theUsername.addTextNode(username);
    QName passwordQName = new QName(SECURITY_NAMESPACE, "Password");
    SOAPElement thePassword = soapFactory.createElement(passwordQName);
    thePassword.addTextNode(password);
    usernameToken.addChildElement(theUsername);
    usernameToken.addChildElement(thePassword);
    security.addChildElement(usernameToken);
```

where username and password are the same as what's in testFile.dat.

security part of testFile.dat request is:

```
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
     <wsu:Timestamp>
        <wsu:Created>2016-02-19T16:36:21Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2016-02-19T16:41:21Z</wsu:Expires>
     </wsu:Timestamp>
     <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
        <wsu:Created>2016-02-19T16:36:21Z</wsu:Created>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the following 2 lines when they changed the endpoint of their web service

```
QName pwdTypeQName = new QName("Type");
thePassword.addAttribute(pwdTypeQName, "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText");
```